# layout_window is not defined even if i defined it

Tags: python, layout, window, undefined

I did a game from a coding book in python and it says layout_window is not defined even if i wrote 
def layout_window(window):
here is my code

```
import tkinter
import random
gameOver = False
score = 0
squaresToClear = 0
def play_bombdodger():
    create_bombfield(bombfield)
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    layout_window(window)
    window.mainloop
bombfield = []
def create_bombfield(bombfield):
    global squaresToClear
    for row in range(0,10):
        rowList = []
        for column in range(0,10):
            if random.randint(1,100) < 20:
                rowList.append(1)
            else:
                rowList.append(0)
                squaresToClear = squaresToClear + 1
        bombfield.append(rowList)
        printfield(bombfield)
def printfield(bombfield):
    for rowList in bombfield:
        print(rowList)
play_bombdodger()
def layout_window(window):
    for rowNumber, rowList in enumerate(bombfield):
        for columnNumber, columnEntry in enumerate(bombfield):
            if random.randint(1,100) < 25:
                square = tkinter.Label(window, text = "    ", bg = "darkgreen")
```

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `play_bombdodger` which calls `layout_window`, but you call `play_bombdodget` before you define `layout_window`.

Comment: Now it says globalSquaresToclear its not defined the book doesn't say where to define it